# Warning: Attempt to present <MyViewController: 0x10c5771a0> on <UINavigationController: 0x10c533da0> whose view is not in the window hierarchy

Tags: ios, objective-c, segue

I am trying to segue to my ViewController with this code:

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"iPhone_Storyboard" bundle:nil];
UIViewController *vc = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"details"];
[self presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:nil];
```

However I get this error message:

```
Warning: Attempt to present <MyViewController: 0x10c5771a0> on <UINavigationController: 0x10c533da0> whose view is not in the window hierarchy!
```

I am calling the segue in the UIAlertView Delegate Method:

```
-(void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{

}
```

Comment: Inside which method you are executing the segue code?

Comment: Tryy delaying the segure code block by 0.1.

Comment: @doNotCheckMyBlog Does not work :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your UIAlertView's window is the frontmost UIWindow, so your view controller can't present. You need to wait until the alert view dismisses. The simplest way is to use `alertView:didDismissWithButtonIndex:` (instead of clickedButtonAtIndrx).

Answer (score 0):

add this too, it worked for me.

```
lvc.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFormSheet;
lvc.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical;

[mvc presentModalViewController:lvc animated:YES];
```